# Is it acceptable solution to set session.gc_maxlifetime in hook_init()?

Tags: sessions

We need to set session.gc_maxlifetime separately on the site and mobile (app).
Is any best practices here?

UPD. My final solution looks as follows:

```
$args = arg();
$is_mob_rest_api = FALSE;
if (!empty($args)) {
  $is_mob_rest_api = $args[0] == 'api' && $args[1] == 'v1';
}
$session__gc_maxlifetime = $is_mob_rest_api ? 31536000 : 1440;
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $session__gc_maxlifetime);
```

Comment: `hook_init()` isn't invoked for cached pages, so likely not. `hook_boot()` is, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set it always and for all, you should do it in *settings.php*

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',  36000);
```